# PHP pagination on table

Tags: php

So for a school project, I'm making an inventory system, one of the pages contains a table with all the available stock. But there is way too much data to display in the table and I don't want the table to be 300 records long. So i decided I wanted to implement pagination on the already existing table. Now the thing is that I have no idea where to begin. I'm doing this with Object-oriented PHP. I hope someone can send me into the right direction of where to begin.

PHP code where i fill my table with data:

```
<?php

require_once('classes/Database.php');
$db = new Database;

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM producten");

$count = $query->rowCount();
if($count > 0) {
while($row = $query->fetch())
  {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td id='td1'>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td id='td2'>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td id='td3'>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td id='td4'>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td id='td4'>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td id='td5'><a onclick='document.getElementById(\"id\").value=".$row[0]."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' href=''><img data-toggle='tooltip' data-id='$row[0]' data-placement='top' title='Edit' src='img/edit.svg' height='25'></a></td>";
        echo "<td id='td6'><a id='btn_link' href='php/Delete.php?id=".$row[0]."'><img data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Delete' src='img/delete_2.svg' height='25'></a></td>";
        //echo "<td  id='td5'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}
?>
```

Then in my HTML file, I just include this PHP file so it's being displayed on the page.

Comment: Bootstrap Datatables

Comment: Look into the MySQL `LIMIT` clause

Comment: _“Now the thing is that I have no idea where to begin.”_ - why not? This is everything but a new topic, so you should be able to find plenty of resources that explain the basics of how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using jQuery DataTables https://datatables.net/, its very easy and useful for handle many record and support Server-side processing .

Comment: Hey Javier, somehow when I add the CDN's and the jquery to my code, it's not working. Could this be because I'm filling my table in an external file?

Comment: I already fixed the problem, apparently I put the CDN's in the wrong order.

Comment: Nice, remember use "server processing" for database

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap datatable with zero configuration.
Here is the [link](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)
You can easily configure as per your preferences and requirements. Go through the docs they are easy to understand.

Other way would be:
Use Mysql query with `limit` and `offset` but that would be another long way around though.